# Need Angular 4+ (data transfer to another component)

Tags: angular

Problem in data transfer (from one component to another)
[enter image description here]
There are two components DetectparamComponent DetectorComponent
In the `DetectorComponent`, I get to write data and I need to pass the value of this variable to `DetectparamComponent` (in fact, I pull the data out of the table and use it in another component)

I just do not know how to make the transfer (due to lack of experience)
I thought first through the service (сomp1-> serv-> comp2) didn't work
As far as I understand, if you use `@input`, then all html is dragged, but I need only 1 value from the ts file

Comment: Here's a simple example using `Subject` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Comment: but I just need a variable to pass between ts, not dragging html data from one component to another

Comment: what is the relation between these two components?

Comment: In your example helloComponent is child to appComponent so you can share data with `@input` `@output` decorators. Your updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wa1tvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

try this

In HTML Of First Component

```
<a (click)="onSelect(data)">Go to </a>
```

In FirstComponent

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private router: Router) {
   }
   onSelect(data) {
      this.router.config.find(r => r.component == SecondComponent).data = data;
      this.router.navigate(["Second Component routing path"]);
   }
}
```

In Second Component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
   SentItem : any;
   constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.router.data.subscribe(r=>this.SentItem =r);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your servicename.ts file, you can create a Subject type property as a private and then create another property and make it as observable.
Here's an example

**servicename.ts**

```
export class servicename { 
    private propertytosend = new Subject<any>();
    propertytosend$ = this.propertytosend.asObservable();
    private data = 'Hello';
    // Method to call from outside the component through service
    // like in any component that is on the same page as the component we are getting
    // data in
    public getData() { 
       this.propertytosend.next(this.data);
    }
}
```

In the component you want to get the data in you have to write following code in the constructor using the servicename object.

```
this.servicename.propertytosend$.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
})
```

Hope this helps